# Where is the 'comix' linux program library database stored?

Tags: linux

I know it's not on ~/.confix/comix/preferences.pickle since i checked that file and it has no paths or the definitions of the comic books names and paths i input to my current library.

I want to know the file that holds this information so i can backup it. I know it's probably a sql database from snooping around the comix github, but i can't figure out which.

https://github.com/Joacchim/Comix

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, navigated the confusing maze of indirection in the source.
it's ~/.local/share/comix/library.db